# Can linq predicates be combined here?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am using EF4.3 with a unit-of-work + repository pattern.

I have a method which act as a base of some other methods, here's how the code looks.

This is my 'base' method:

```
    public static IQueryable<Deal> FindActive()
    {
        var r = new ReadRepo<Deal>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

        return r.Find(d =>
            d.ActiveFrom <= DateTime.Now &&
            (d.ActiveUntilComputed == null || d.ActiveUntilComputed > DateTime.Now) &&
            d.Published);
    }
```

Here is one of the methods that calls the base method:

```
    public static IQueryable<Deal> FindActiveByStore(int storeId)
    {
        Guard.Default(storeId, "storeId");
        return FindActive().Where(d => d.StoreId == storeId);
    }
```

As you can see in `FindActiveByStore`, I first call `FindActive`, which then chains `Find()`. FindActive is followed by a `Where()` to add a secondary predicate (excuse the terminology).

I wondered if it was possible to pass a predicate to `FindActive` instead of using a `Where()`, and in fact whether it would make a difference in terms of performance.

Like this:

```
FindActive(d => d.StoreId == storeId)
```

FindActive already passes a predicate to `Find()` so it would need to combine both.

I'm guessing that the answers I get back will be along the lines 'its not worth it' in terms of effort or performance but I thought i'd ask the experts anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code (You reduce number lines of code)

```
public IQueryable<Deal> FindActiveByStore(Expression<Func<Deal,bool>> predicate)
{
  var r = new ReadRepo<Deal>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

  return r.Find(d => d.ActiveFrom <= DateTime.Now 
             && (d.ActiveUntilComputed == null || d.ActiveUntilComputed > DateTime.Now) 
             && d.Published)

             .Where(predicate);   
}
```

Comment: odd. adding .Where(m => m.AnotherField != null) works but .Where(predicate) doesn't) - comes up with syntax ...doesn't contain a definition for 'Where'

Comment: @user1437135 because there's  a mix between a Generic predicate (T)` and Deal. If you replace T by Deal in the definition of the function, it will work